# JMeter- Master server failed to start and return [No route to host (Host unreachable)]

Tags: amazon-ec2, jmeter, distributed-testing

I try to run a distributed test using JMeter, I have 2 EC2 instances

Master Public IP: 54.xxx.xx.xx
Slave Public IP: 204.xxx.xxx.xxx

I have opened all the necessary ports that were used in the configuration.

I can ping each EC2 from the other one and the ping is successful.

But when I try to start the test, the server failed and return [No route to host (Host unreachable)].

My plan is to use more than 1 slave.

[Error Return From Master Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Cnj.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per [NoRouteToHostException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NoRouteToHostException.html) exception description:

> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the remote host cannot be reached because of an **intervening firewall**, or if an intermediate router is down.

So make sure that the RMI ports which JMeter slave is listening are:

1. Not dynamic
2. Open in your operating system [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))
3. Open in [EC2 Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html)

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)

Comment: I double-checked all points you mention:
RMI ports on slave is not dynamic, and the selected port is Open in EC2 Security groups for all network traffic.
Still, the same issue, is there any other possible solution?